# Disable enumerative behavior for name collisions across controllers

Tags: openapi, springfox

I am generating code for my Angular Clients using Springfox.

One of my controllers `MenuCardController` has a method `getAll()` which looks as follows:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = CONTROLLER_ROOT + "/menu-cards", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PageableAsQueryParam
public Page<MenuCard> getAll(
        @PathVariable(name = "businessId") Long businessId,
        @Parameter(hidden = true) Pageable pageable
) {
    return this.menuCardService.getAll(businessId, pageable);
}
```

However, the generated code looks like this:

```js
getAll1(businessId: number, page?: number, size?: number, sort?: Array<string>, observe?: 'body', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<PageMenuCard>;
getAll1(businessId: number, page?: number, size?: number, sort?: Array<string>, observe?: 'response', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<HttpResponse<PageMenuCard>>;
getAll1(businessId: number, page?: number, size?: number, sort?: Array<string>, observe?: 'events', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<HttpEvent<PageMenuCard>>;
```

This is essentially correct but for some reason there is a `1` appended to the name. This controller does not have any other method which is called `getAll`.

Looking at other generated code I got:

```js
getAll3(businessId: number, observe?: 'body', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<Array<PaymentMethodModel>>;
getAll3(businessId: number, observe?: 'response', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<HttpResponse<Array<PaymentMethodModel>>>;
getAll3(businessId: number, observe?: 'events', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<HttpEvent<Array<PaymentMethodModel>>>;
```

So the question is whether it is possible to turn this behavior off. It seems that e.g. `getAll` gets "reserved" globally for the entire API and not just for one `<name>ControllerService` object.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `@Api`:

```java
@Api("Menu Card")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/menucard")
public class MenuCardController {
```

Comment: The `@Api` annotation does not seem to exist in my setup. Currently I have `springdoc-openapi-ui` and `springdoc-openapi-data-rest` from `org.springdoc` in my dependencies.